# Pass string from html to python script

Tags: python, html, string, web

I need help, I have a Python script that do some work and print html web page.
I need to pass string from that outputed web page to that script.
Is that possible ? 
In future I want to use radio buttons where user will thick data for plotting from predefinned ones.
Thanks for any advice...

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
import subprocess
import os

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
web = """

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div id='wrapper'>
        <div id='header'>

        </div>

        <div id='content'>
            <div class='content'>
                <div><h3>GRAPH</h3></div>
                <br>
                <div style='height:520px;width:1000px;overflow:scroll;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;'>
                    <img src='http://localhost/steps.png' alt='image' />
                </div>
                <br>    
                <button onclick="myFunction()">REFRESH</button>
                <script>
                    function myFunction() {
                    location.reload();
                    }
                </script>

                <br>

                <form action='/cgi-bin/test.py' method='post'>
                    nazov suboru: <input type='text' data='data'> <br />
                <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
                </form>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>          
</body>
</html>
"""

print web
proc = subprocess.Popen(['gnuplot','-p'], 
                        shell=True,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )

proc.communicate("""
reset
set terminal pngcairo enhanced size 3000,500 font 'Arial,11' rounded; 
set output '/opt/lampp/htdocs/%s.png'

set datafile separator "|"
plot \
\
'%s.txt' u 0:3 sm cs w l ls 1  t 'X-suradnice',\
'%s.txt' u 0:4 sm cs w l ls 2  t 'Y-suradnice',\
'%s.txt' u 0:5 sm cs w l ls 3  t 'Z-suradnice'
"""%(data,data,data,data))
```

Comment: I am really new to this. IS there any way to do it simple ? I mean somehow save to string what user write... ?

Comment: @tdelaney surely OP is not asking about scraping, but about how to get a text field submitted in a CGI script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite hard to understand, but I think you are trying to work out how to access the `data` parameter submitted by the form POST. You can do that with the `cgi` module:

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
data = form.getvalue('data')
```